# One-Jar for Applet

Tags: java, ant, jar, applet, onejar

I have an applet that needs to import another libraries. I used Apache Ant to build this applet and libraries into same jar files, but there is no way to connect classes with libraries. I got NoClassDefFoundError.

Because of that I decided to use one-jar with Ant. One-jar creates a jar files that contains libraries and classes. But classes that I wrote are in another jar inside of main jar. Directory looks like below :

- main.jar

  - com
  - doc
  - lib
  - main

    - applets.jar

      - MyApplet.class

I need to access MyApplet class in applets.jar file but problem is that how can I import my applet class which is in second jar. It's not possible to write second attribute in applet tag.

Is there any option in one-jar to build only one jar with libraries? What should I use?

Answer (score 1):

> It's not possible to write second attribute in applet tag.

Then it is a good thing there is no need to.  The `archive` attribute of the `applet` element can list multiple Jars, which is how you should approach this.

Comment: Andrew, but applet which I want to access is inside of first jar, can I write archive like this : 
`archive = "main.jar, applets.jar"`

Comment: You can write it any way you like!  But then ..what happened when you *tried it?*

Comment: it throwed exception :
`ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error`

Actually I didn't understand that is it possible to write jar name which is inside of main jar in `archive` attribute?

Comment: Any comment about my main problem? How can I add applet which is inside of second jar?

Comment: OK I'm a little confused.  If you have both Jars listed in the `archive` attribute, it is simply a matter of adding the Fully Qualified Name of any applet in any of the Jars as the `code` attribute in order to load it in HTML.  How does that *not* work for you?

Comment: I think I can not use archive attribute for my two JARs, because they are nested, applet JAR is in main JAR. I wanna use applet class in web page. Directory of JAR is in my post.

Comment: *"because they are nested"*  Well my point is **Don't nest them.**  Just add each Jar to the `archive` attribute!  Also, please refrain from using slang like 'wanna'.  If someone who speaks English as a 2nd language is trying to help you, they may have to use Google translate to understand.  I don't know how it handles slang, but best not test it.  Also ..I detest seeing slang in technical posts.  It does not put me in a mood conducive to helping.

Comment: Using libraries seperately is more complicated for my situation, because there are a lot of libraries that applet needs to import. So I thought that better approach is using them nested as a JAR.

Comment: *"Using libraries seperately is more complicated for my situation.."*  (Reviews thread, and comments.)  And this lot seems ..simple?!?  Applets are (and always have been) a complete PITA to develop, deploy and maintain.  See [this blog post](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for my views on the matter.

Comment: Oh, also note:  For 'jar in a jar' to work requires a custom class-loader, which in turn requires a trusted applet.  It *really* complicates matters.

Comment: Oh, seems like it will be more complicated increasingly, I've spent a week to solve. Well, sorry but is there any way to build JAR from classes and libraries together? I want to build a JAR file that doesn't need anything, all dependencies should be in that JAR.
Note that I can not choose technology that we use, so I must solve problem using Applet.

Comment: *"..is there any way to build JAR from classes and libraries together?"*  Sure there is, but there are also *good reasons **not** to do that,* including violating the license of 3rd party APIs, destruction of necessary information in the manifests of those Jars..  I could go on, but I won't.  ***Just do it the standard way!***